# scala: upper and lower bounds in functions between classes

Tags: scala

Assuming that

```
class SpecificAPI extends APIConnection{
   def annotate(...) = //definition of annotate function
}
```

I have a class father:

```
class Father{
   protected def processMessage[A<:APIConnection](recordToAnalyze: RecordToAnalyze, api:Option[A] = None): Option[IndexEnrichment]
}

class Child extends Father{
   override def processMessage[SpecificAPI](recordToAnalyze: RecordToAnalyze, api: Option[SpecificAPI]): Option[IndexEnrichment] = {

    api.get.annotate(...) //I cannot access to this function
}
```

Why I cannot access to methods of the `SpecificAPI` in the Child class?

Basically I want to define a generic method to instantiate che connection to different APIs and I want to change only the function `processMessage` in the Children classes. Am I missing something?

Comment: There is confusion between type name and name of type parameter for the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `SpecificAPI` in class `Child` is the type parameter. So it is the same as actually typing `processMessage[A]` ...

What you probably want is to lift type parameter to class definition, so you can pass the `SpecificApi` to the `Child`:

```
class Father[A<:APIConnection]{
   protected def processMessage(recordToAnalyze: RecordToAnalyze, api:Option[A] = None): Option[IndexEnrichment]
}

class Child extends Father[SpecificAPI]{
   override def processMessage(recordToAnalyze: RecordToAnalyze, api: Option[SpecificAPI]): Option[IndexEnrichment] = {

    api.get.annotate(...) //I cannot access to this function
}
```

As a side note, do not use get directly on `Option`, unless you did it just to make this example.

Comment: Ha! This is interesting! Strangely enough, you have proposed exactly the same "solution" to an extremely ill-posed problem, which is underdetermined in every way possible. This is a strong indication that it might actually be "the correct solution", whatever this means...

Comment: How does it work? You and @AndreyTyukin gave the same answer.. "I see voices" though has Sans from Undertale's avatar

Comment: Well, this seems to be a solution which is very likely to be more or less correct in most contexts, and is as close to the original code as possible. It's still a bit surprising, because the space of possible solutions isn't exactly small. That's what you learn Haskell for: you can see "the correct solution" even through thick walls. ;)

Comment: That was actually funny, because the timing was about 10 seconds different :).

Answer (score 1):

The type parameter `SpecificAPI` in the `processMessage` of the `Child` class is an unconstrained type parameter with an extremely confusing name. If you want to understand better what your code does, rename it to `X`:

```
class Child extends Father{
  override def processMessage[X](
    recordToAnalyze: RecordToAnalyze, 
    api: Option[X]
  ): Option[IndexEnrichment] = {
    api.get.annotate(...) //I cannot access to this function
    // Well, why should an arbitrary `X` have method `annotate`?
  }
}
```

Now it should be obvious that this cannot compile.

I have a vague feeling that you might have meant something like this:

```
trait APIConnection
class IndexEnrichment
class RecordToAnalyze

class SpecificAPI extends APIConnection {
  def annotate(): Unit = ???
}

trait Father [A <: APIConnection] {
  protected def processMessage(
    recordToAnalyze: RecordToAnalyze, 
    api:Option[A] = None
  ): Option[IndexEnrichment]
}

class Child extends Father[SpecificAPI] {
  override def processMessage(
    recordToAnalyze: RecordToAnalyze, 
    api: Option[SpecificAPI]
  ): Option[IndexEnrichment] = {
    api.get.annotate()
    ???
  }
}
```

Comment: You made it clear what I misunderstood about type name. 
>Well, why should an arbitrary `X` have method `annotate`? 
sure :D

Comment: What about the "educated guess" in the rest of the answer? Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it well . But my problem was exactly this. I thought I could extract the type inside the definition method. But I should have put the type parameter in the class definition. Thank you guys.